# Close flag disputed

Tags: support, triage, disputed-flags

I recently left a close flag for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762057/how-can-i-build-vpn-app-by-using-vpnservice), that I reviewed in the Triage queue.

To my understanding, there are three appropriate reasons to close that question:

> - Too broad
> - Unclear what you're asking
> - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I see that my flag has been disputed, and I don't understand why. Am I or the flag reviewers wrong? If I'm wrong, what have I specifically misunderstood?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[The triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23367255) review for that post resulted in 3 people saying it looks okay, two saying it needs editing, and  your flag.

The people saying that post is good as it is were just *really, really* wrong.  Like, completely inappropriately so.  As for editing, there are lots of problems with that post that *can* be fixed with editing, but...lots that can't, so that's also wrong, although I'm less inclined to go with gross negligence on a review like that.  This is bad enough that it's worth flagging to have a mod look over the review and consider taking some action.

But you're completely right that the post is not only *extremely* broad, poorly defined in what it's asking for, and is requesting references to external resources, just as you said.

On a bit of a tangent, but any of those close reasons would work, although I'd personally choose Too Broad as it's the problem that's least fixable of the three it's discouraging to close a question, have the author fix that one problem, and then have to tell them the question won't be reopened because it also has some other problem, so I generally choose the close reason that's hardest to fix, such that fixing it likely fixes all other problems too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your last point should probably be written as something like "choose the least fixable error" above the list of close reasons, although we should be able to list more reasons, and lock reopening of posts if 2/3+ reasons qualify. Would also have been useful if reviewers could view past reviewers' actions.

Comment: @Andreas That's not official policy, just my personal advice.  Official policy is you're free to choose any close reason that's valid.  Don't fret *too* much over which close reason to choose when many apply.  That's just what I personally use as my tiebreaker.

Comment: @Andreas Having more complex features like closing for multiple reasons, changing close reasons, require reopening of each in turn, etc. all sound like good ideas at first, but they add a lot of complexity, both for those closing/reopening posts, and people trying to understand what's happening to their own question (or one they're interested in seeing answered).

Comment: We would on the other hand not have to track our flags, and repost them as "questions" on MSO...

Comment: "...generally choose the close reason that's hardest to fix..." This is really very valuable advice. And if this close reason actually gets fixed, one could also start talking about the other possible close reasons.

Comment: @Andreas You can see the past review actions of other users/reviewers. That information is in their profile ("Activity" tab➞"All actions" sub-tab➞"Reviews" sub-sub-tab). For example, your review actions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7395227/andreas?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Comment: @Trilarion Easier to mark them all at once, and not have to worry about the post again, before all are fixed.

Comment: @Andreas Sounds good at first sight, but then how do you know that all are fixed? Should reopen voters then mark all the things that are fixed too?

Comment: @ Trilarion Seems like a good way to do it, for me.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland It would be easier fixing it if getting the easiest problems to fix first, but if a question has that many issues, it's probably simply unsalvageable, and should be deleted. Oh, hey, I found a new question on the list of related ones to the one I flagged, and flagged [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958351/android-vpn-app-using-android-vpnservice) for being too broad, as well. Seems like a candidate for not being reopened, ever. Could also be flagged for off-site recommendations.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland The example question here is a great example of this.  The question is both super broad and yet still unclear on what precisely it's asking (the incomplete information we do have on what it's asking suggests it's really broad, but we're not really sure precisely what's being asked).  You could close the question as unclear and they could make it clearer that they are in fact asking for an extremely broad topic, which would then still merit closure, and they'll have wasted all of their time trying to clarify the question.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Or you could close the question as Too Broad, and they'll realize they need to come up with a much more specific question, which they will hopefully describe more clearly when they do, and if not, clarifying *that* question will be a completely different process than clarifying the broad question anyway.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland The other factor is working around how the close system is designed.  If someone fixes a smaller problem with their question, and yet two other close reasons still apply, you don't want to have to either close and reopen the question (wasting a ton of time from a ton of people, and leaving the question open for bad answers for quite some time in the process), nor do you want the question to just stay closed with a close reason that's not applicable.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland And if you spent 30 seconds writing the question to not ask for a book but for the information you wanted from the book, only to have no one reopen your question because it's too broad, and vague, would that make you feel better?  Also, it takes you a *day* to write the question asking how to get a specific book?  This is a good example of a question that's simply not salvageable.  Trying to get the author to fix it is just going to cause frustration because any question that would be on topic would simply be a new question.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Ehm... It's extremely hard for spectators to follow the discussion if one of the discussants go invisible...